# ContextVars across modules

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-contextvars

I am completely newb on asyncio and `ContextVars`, I just read up what's new in 3.7 and discovered `ContextVars`, I struggle to understand it's usage, all I know it's helpful in coroutines, instead of using `thread.local` should use `ContextVars`. But none of the official doc and top google search result could help me truely understand its purpose.

So is convextvars shared across modules? I tried:

example.py

```
from contextvars import ContextVar

number = ContextVar('number', default=100)
number.set(1)
```

then I try to import number.py

```
(playground) Jamess-MacBook-Pro-2:playground jlin$ python3.7
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import example
>>> from contextvars import ContextVar
>>> number = ContextVar('number', default=200)
>>> number.get()
200
```

I was expecting `number.get()` would return 1, but obviously I have understood its purpose wrong.

Could someone please help me understand this?

Comment: You reassigned `number`, so I would expect `.get()` does return the updated value.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854974/context-variables-in-python

Comment: I thought it would get the value otherwise return the default value?

Answer (score 10):

Assume your use case is to use python `thread.local` to store your thread global variable inside multi thread application.

For example you store django `request` globally in `thread.local`

- all your code has access to current (and correct) `request` instance
- it works, **because each django HTTP request handled in it's own python thread**

No imagine you handle HTTP requests in asyncio as non blocking code executed in the same python thread.

- HTTP request stored in `thread.local` isn't going to work, because multiple concurrent requests get processed in the same python thread
- What happens is **you overwrite same `thread.local` variable** and all your code has access to latest (incorrect) `request` instance

In this case you use `ContextVars` designed to be used for this use case inside non blocking concurrent jobs running in same python thread.

Answer (score 2):

You are reassigning the value of `number`.  Directly call the variable from the module, e.g. `example.number.get()`.

---

A simple application is substituting a global variable.

**Given**

```
import random
import contextvars as cv
```

**Code**

Here we'll imitate a random walk.  Like a global variable, we are able to share state between functions:

```
move = cv.ContextVar("move", default="")


def go_left():
    value = move.get()
    move.set(value + "L")


def go_right():
    value = move.get()
    move.set(value + "R")


def random_walk(steps):
    directions = [go_left, go_right]
    while steps:
        random.choice(directions)()
        steps -= 1
    return move.get()
```

**Demo**

The `ContextVar` acts as a global variable that is updated by random events:

```
random_walk(1)
# 'R'
random_walk(2)
# 'RLL'
random_walk(3)
# 'RLLLRL'
```

Beyond a regular global variable, `ContextVar`:

- permits [default values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#contextvars.ContextVar)
- works with [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#manual-context-management)
- works with [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#module-contextvars)

Comment: OK, so when other modules needs to use the same contextvar, it needs to import it?

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the value for the number again. Which is why it shows 200 from the latest update.

Comment: Which statement I assign the value again? I thought default is if there is no value then assign 200?

Answer (score -1):

Not completely sure if my approach is correct but I will add my findings to answer, so I tried to use this in my django project to set the `request` var without using thread local.

```
from contextvars import ContextVar
request_var = ContextVar('request', default=None)


def request_middleware(get_response):
    """
    Sets the request into contextvar
    """
    def middleware(request):
        ctx = copy_context()
        return ctx.run(wrap_get_response, request)

    def wrap_get_response(request):
        request_var.set(request)
        return get_response(request)
    return middleware
```

Then in somewhere else that need to use the `request` var:

```
from core.middlewares import request_var
request = request_var.get()
```

Not sure if this is the correct usage, but it seems working fine for me.

I don't know how to get the request_var from context.get() eg.

```
from contextvars import copy_context
ctx = copy_context()
# the key here is `request_var` obj in middlewares.py, 
# might as well just import `request_var` and use it directly?
request = ctx.get(...)
```