# getting a value from a context by name

Tags: python

I want to use context vars for a similar purpose like in this question and accepted answer: [Context variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854974/context-variables-in-python)

That corresponds to `f3a()` in this example:

```
import contextvars

user_id = contextvars.ContextVar("user_id_var")

def test():
    user_id.set("SOME-DATA")
    f2()

def f2():
    f3a()
    f3b()

def f3a():
    print(user_id.get()) 

def f3b():
    ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
    for key, value in ctx.items():
        if key.name == 'user_id_var':
            print(value)
            break

test()
```

However the function needs the `user_id` global variable to get the value. If it were in a different module, it would need to import it.

My idea was that if a function knows there exists a context and it knows the variable name, that should be all it needs. I wrote the `f3b`, but as you can see, I have to search all variables, because context vars do not support lookup by name. Lookup by variable is implemented, but if I had the variable, I could get the value directly from it (`f3a` case)

I'm afraid I do not understand why it was designed the way it was. Why an agreed-upon name is not a key? If a context is set in some kind of framework and then used by application code, those two functions will be in different modules without a common module global var. The examples I could find did not help me. Could somebody please explain the rationale behind the context vars API?

Comment: I have the same issue. It would be really interesting to have a `Context.get()` method by name.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I worked out to make it actually make sense when I use it:

```
ctx = {ctx_var.name: {"context_var": ctx_var, "value": value} for ctx_var, value in copy_context().items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also annoyed by this interface - here's an explanation of this design choice from Chat GPT:

> Python's contextvars module is designed to provide a way to manage
> context-specific state, such as data that should not be shared between
> different asynchronous tasks or threads. The design choice to use the
> actual `ContextVar` instance as a key, rather than its name, is mainly
> due to two reasons: encapsulation and avoidance of naming conflicts.
>
> 1. Encapsulation: By requiring the use of the actual `ContextVar` instance as the key, the module encourages users to treat context
>    variables as proper objects, rather than mere strings. This promotes
>    encapsulation, making it easier to reason about the code and maintain
>    it. When a context variable is accessed from a different module, it's
>    usually better to import and use the actual `ContextVar` instance
>    instead of relying on a string name. This approach reduces the risk of
>    mistakes and naming conflicts.
> 2. Avoiding naming conflicts: If the `Context` object allowed accessing values using the name of a `ContextVar`, there would be a
>    higher risk of naming conflicts. Different modules could accidentally
>    use the same name for different context variables, leading to
>    unexpected behavior. By using the `ContextVar` instance as the key,
>    the risk of such conflicts is significantly reduced.
>
> While this design choice might make accessing context variables from
> different modules slightly less convenient, it is intended to
> encourage better software design practices and prevent issues caused
> by naming conflicts. If you need to share a `ContextVar` between
> modules, you can define the variable in a shared module and import it
> in the modules that need to access it.

I took the advice of instantiating ContextVars in a separate shared module - it ends up working quite nicely.

That said, if you'd still like access context with a string, here's another solution:

```py
from contextvars import copy_context, ContextVar, Context
from typing import Optional

def get_from_context(ctx: Context, k: str) -> Optional[ContextVar]:
    try:
        return next(filter(lambda v: v.name == k, ctx.keys()))
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get the value of key **user_id** by this way

```
user_id = contextvars.ContextVar("user_id_var")
ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
ctx[user_id]
# or
ctx.get(user_id)
```

I saw in the [official document](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0567/) they have mention something that might related to your concern:

> The notion of "current value" deserves special consideration: different asynchronous tasks that exist and execute concurrently may have different values for the same key

and [Making Context objects picklable](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0567/#making-context-a-mutablemapping)

Comment: This does not answer my question.